# Javascript sort object by second value

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
Object {
  "1468": "Test Prop",
  "1647": "TEST 1",
  "1820": "ABC",
  "1840": "Gio"
}
```

I would like to order by the second property. It would be:

```
Object {
  "1820": "ABC",
  "1840": "Gio",
  "1647": "TEST 1",
  "1468": "Test Prop"
}
```

How can I do it in Javascript?

I received the data in an array:

```
Array [
  Array [
    1820,
    "ABC",
  ],
  Array [
    1840,
    "Gio",
  ],
  Array [
    1647,
    "Test 1",
  ],
  Array [
    1468,
    "Test Prop",
  ],
]
```

It is already ordered, but when I create my object I lost the order:

```
const myObj = {};
for (let index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
   const value = data[index];
   myObj[value[0]] = value[1];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Property order in an object is defined by the language based on the order in which the properties were added over the object's lifetime. You can't control the ordering based on your own criteria.

Comment: I guess you can remove and re-add them but even that ordering is implementation specific.

Comment: I just included my array data and the object creation